# Hamstring injury - has it healed?

Tags: hamstring

While playing squash 4 weeks ago, I made a false step and felt a snap in my hamstring. There was no immediate pain associated to it. However, when it cooled down, it made me limp a bit.

From what I read on the net, this is maybe more than a pull, but not a severe tear.

I've rested for the past 4 weeks, and I'm not sure it has healed. When I stretch it, I feel a sort of 'knotted' muscle sensation right above the knee on the backside. The pain from stretching is a bit more acute than what I would feel while stretching my healthy hamstring. However, I can almost achieve normal mobility with it.

How can I tell the hamstring is healed, and the pain I feel is not simply coming from the fact that the leg was injured and inactive for 4 weeks, thus being harder to stretch ?

Comment: This is too medical to fit the scope of this site; please review the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell, and, nor can we.  Only a trained professional can advise you on the extent of the trauma to the muscle.  Having said that, you should let your pain level guide you to amount and extent of the activity as you ease back into it.  Ideally you would have progressed through some sort of rehab program to strengthen the injured area.